# Errors when playing rtsp video with vlcj library

Tags: java, javafx, vlc, vlcj

I have an issue when playing videos with vlcj.
I'm reading RTSP video streams from 5 cameras.

these are some samples of the errors I receive:

My app runs on Oracle Linux with nvidia video card (and also nvidia drivers)
The error start appearing after some hours

Haver anyone Ideas about how can I fix them?

Also after about 10 hrs gnome shell start lagging (quite much) but the app is still responsive, after 24 hours all freezes.

```
[00007f8e180d47d0] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8e4c05b200] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8e4c05b200] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8e4c05b200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8e4c05b200] no frame!
[00007f8e14259f90] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1449 ms)
[00007f8e0c084ef0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 4261 ms)
[00007f8e44019140] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 4145 ms)
[00007f8e240110f0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 4272 ms)
[h264 @ 0x7f8e9c17f500] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7f8e6c0ee340] co located POCs unavailable
[00007f8e200ebe50] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f8e4815a840] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f8e180d47d0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[h264 @ 0x7f8c5c001ec0] co located POCs unavailable
[00007f8e5009a9f0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f8e5009a9f0] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8c5c001ec0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8c5c001ec0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8c5c001ec0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8c5c001ec0] no frame!
```

```
[h264 @ 0x7f8d94197800] co located POCs unavailable
[00007f8bdae512c0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
```

```
[00007f8bdae512c0] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  470.161.03  Wed Oct 19 00:03:46 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[00007f8d7c14b930] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  470.161.03  Wed Oct 19 00:03:46 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[00007f8d7c14b930] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f8d8536d260] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  470.161.03  Wed Oct 19 00:03:46 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[00007f8d7c14b930] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
```

```
[00007f8d8536d260] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8d90094980] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8d90094980] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8d90094980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8d90094980] no frame!
[00007f8d78148d40] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007f8d701a6dc0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007f8d68179710] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007f8d80008690] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007f8d7c14b930] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8d9401bfc0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8d9401bfc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8d9401bfc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8d9401bfc0] no frame!
[00007f8bdae512c0] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
```

Comment: Not sure but have a look at the following. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95420/raspivid-es-out-set-group-pcr-is-called-too-late-stream-keeps-freezing